# Excluding JSPs from trim-filter

Tags: jsp

In web.xml I have the jsp names that are to be excluded from the trim-filter.

Trim-filter will remove the extra spaces from the jsp.

Some jsps need that trim filter and some are to be excluded. How can I exclude jsps from the trim-filter in the run time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't exclude in your web.xml.But you  can do like below in your trimFilter.

```
// get the file being requested  
    String file = request.getServletPath();  

    if (file.equals(yourjspname))  
        chain.doFilter(req, res);  
    else  
        // do the other things
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Trim Filter ver. 2.5 API says you can do like below..Parameter

> exclude

contains regular expresion to match excluded urls..By default this parameter is empty (do not exclude files).

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>trimFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.cj.trim.trimFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>exclude</param-name>
    <param-value>/login.jsp</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```